# Angular 7 direct print receipt

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to print receipt directly with angular 7. I don't need the print preview. I want to select the printer and proceed to print. Is there any plugin or example to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngx-print` for that.

Plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/print-in-angular)

```
<div id="print-section"> 
  <!--Your html stuff that you want to print-->
</div>
<button printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```